# Why did PV cell manufacturing move away from having all of the contacts in the lower end of a PV cell?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

In modern day PV cells you usually have a silver-based grid on the upper end of the cell where it's exposed to the sun creating the optimization game of how thin/thick you can make your busbars and fingers so that maximum current can be passed without covering too much of the silicone surface blocking the sun's exposure to the n-type surface.

In the early silicon cells they used to design the cells in the following way:

[image: PN Junction where P covers the entire n-type layer except the lower end where the contacts are mounted]

Source: https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/manufacturing-si-cells/early-silicon-cells

Why did they stop with this approach? Was it just fabrication costs? This seems more intuitive as you're maximizing the surface area of the layer exposed to the sun?

Comment: That grid has been on solar cells since the 1970s at least (in personal experience). What is shown in your picture is something that can only be done after slicing things up, and is actually quite hard to do (conformal coating around the edges of a part).

Comment: I agree with @JonCuster. How could the structure in your picture be manufactured?

Comment: I also suspect that even highly doped silicon is still a couple of orders of magnitude less conductive than metals, so the performance at high current densities would be pretty poor, but I didn't look up the numbers. A possible solution to that would be to drill small holes (vias) into the material that could be filled with a metal. At the end of the day most likely none of these techniques is economically worth it. The only major breakthrough here would be cells with much higher efficiency (40% and higher), but a combination of solar with agriculture might make even that superfluous.

Comment: @JohnDoty updated the source link. I accidentally referenced the image source URL rather than the article's URL!

Comment: The article quotes a 6% efficiency for that structure, much less than modern PV cells. So, it didn't work very well, for reasons that are not clear from what is written.